# How access a value from another input inside focus-out function in ember 2?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need read a second value from a input and to do a search. So my component load a complementar info. Follow the form.

```
<form class="col-md-12 form-group">
   {{input type="text" classNames="form-control" placeholder="Place name" name="placeName" }}
   {{input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="09111-620" name="zipcode" focus-out="searchPlace"}}
</form>
```

I need access `placeName` in `focus-out`action. How I do this, after several search in google I don't see a solution using ember 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is simple

```
{{input value=placeNameVal focus-out='placeNameFocusedOut'}} 
{{input value=zipcodeVal focus-out='zipcodeFocusedOut'}}
```

in route or controller

```
actions: {
  zipcodeFocusedOut(zipcodeVal){
   console.log(zipcodeVal);
   console.log(this.get('placeNameVal')); // if you want to get other val
  },
  placeNameFocusedOut(placeNameVal) {
   console.log(placeNameVal);
   console.log(this.get('zipcodeVal')); // if you want to get other val
  }
}
```

Comment: @flpms any success ? please choose as answer if it works

Comment: This is not what I want, but this give me a clue about what I need to do and I solve. Now changed my title. Let me explain agai what I want and how I solved.

I want access `placeName` inside `zipcodeFocusoOut` bind and search for both. 

So I create a property inside the component, to set value after `focusOut` and inside the `zipcodeFocusOut` I read the value.

Comment: @flpms added to my answer

Comment: I try your suggestion in my code, but nothing. Note it's a component, not route ou controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to be able to access whatever is currently in the Place Name field from within your `zipcodeFocusedOut` action.  To do this, you can bind the 'value' attribute of the text field as a property on your route or controller. In your template:

```
<form class="col-md-12 form-group">
   {{input type="text" classNames="form-control" value=placeNameValue placeholder="Place name" name="placeName" }}
   {{input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="09111-620" name="zipcode" focus-out="searchPlace"}}
</form>
```

Instantiate that property as blank in your route or controller, and then you'll be able to refer to it in the action function:

in route or controller:

```
placeNameValue: '',

actions: {
  zipcodeFocusedOut(zipcodeVal){
   console.log(this.get('placeNameValue');
  }
}
```

Any time the text field value is changed, it will automatically change the associated `placeNameValue` field.  In other words, `this.get('placeNameValue')` will always represent the current value of that field, and you can access this anywhere within your controller/route.